# How to set the Session using Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

i am creating simple login programming using seesion.iam a beginner of spring boot how to set the seesion if the username and password correct below it is work successfully if the username and password correct vist to the home page.how to set the session . i want show the seesion on index page.logout also needed

**Login**

```
 @PostMapping("/login")
        public String login(@ModelAttribute("user") User user ) {
            
            if(Objects.nonNull(oauthUser)) 
    {   
        ((User) httpSession).getUsername();
        return "redirect:/";
        
        
    } else {
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
   }
```

index.html

```
<h2>Welcome<h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject session info directy with

```
 @Autowired 
 private HttpSession httpSession;
```

and to get id `httpSession.getId()`

Comment: httpSession.getId(); i put it tell  to unreachable code sir

Comment: If you did it after return statement than no wonder.

Comment: i update above no error now to retieve the session in index.html